# Fetching Index data from elasticsearch DB using Spring Data ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a java code which connects to Elasticsearch DB using Spring-data-elasticsearch and fetches all the index data by connecting to the repository and executing the findAll() method. The data received from ES is being processed by a seperate application. When new data is inserted into elastic search, I have the below queries

```
1. How can I fetch only the newly inserted data Programatically ?
2. Apart from using the DSL queries, Is there a way to Asyncronously get the new records as and when new data is inserted into elasticsearch DB.
```

I dont want to execute the findAll() method again.  Because it returns the entire data ( including the previously processed records as well) .

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a field (I call it `createdAt` here) to your entities that contains the timestamp when your application inserts into Elasticsearch. One possibility would be to use [the auditing support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.6/reference/html/#auditing) of Spring Data Elasticsearch to have the value set automatically, or you set the value in your application. If the data is inserted by some other application you need to make sure that it contains a timestamp in a format that maps the field type definition of this field in your application.

Then you'd need to define a method in your repository like

```java
SearchHits<T> findByCreatedAtAfter(Timestamp referenceValue);
```

As for getting a notification in some form when new data is inserted: I'm not aware that Elasticsearch offers something like that. You will probably need to regularly call the method that retrieves the data.